# Determine age of Raleigh sport womens bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

DA 45169 under bottom bracket
Raleigh ladies sport Steel emblem on front Raleigh Nottingham  England, [image]

Comment: Welcome, the number does not tell anything useful, it is vendor-specific. We need some good photo of the bike.

Comment: Check the rear hub for a date code. They are fairly reliable and there are good data bases  for decoding it. Update your post with that info.  As a side note the crank was likely replaced as it lacks the Raleigh crane in the forging.

Comment: Thanks! On the hub it has Perry England 40 - 14. Is that it or is there another place? Regards Andrew

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** No newer than the late 1970s, and it could be a 60's bike

The cottered cranks were gone by the late 70's which puts a cap on its lower end.

I see the pedals are modern plastic platforms so have been replaced at some point.

The fork crown also appears to have a lock in it - this was intended to lock the steering and make the bike impossible to ride.  However there was nothing stopping the bike being wheeled away on one wheel or carried, so ts functionally like those Dutch rear wheel locks... fairly useless. 
 Also they had a slight risk of catching while stopped, so you'd pull away at a green light and find the bars wouldn't turn.  Removing the lock body was a good fix for that.

I suspect the rear stay for the rear mudguard has been replaced too - its thinner than the front guard's stay, and is clamped in the wheel axle not the dedicated holes for that, so it was a bit longer than the original.

Most importantly - this bike may have had a frontal impact.  It might just be the angle of the photo but the fork's legs/tines appear to bend back below the crown.  It might ride fine if both are bent equally, but even a tiny difference can affect tracking and handling, more so when braking and turning.

---

Is there a bolt in the seatpost clamp?  Can't tell in the photo.  Without one the saddle could twist unexpectedly or drop.

I bet it rides nicely.

Comment: Thanks Criggie, interesting points, it does ride pretty well. I’ll check that fork lock , maybe it locked and the result was the bent forks, it rides straight, just need to pull them forward again. Plus I haven’t checked any of the bearings yet, probably all need maintenance . There is a bolt for the seat post. Regards Andrew